# jQuery Mobile - White space when switching orientation

Tags: jquery, mobile, whitespace

Having an issue with jQuery Mobile when using an iPhone. When I load the page first it loads fine but as soon as I switch orientation it adds white space to the bottom of the background image.

In the orientation style-sheets I just have the code the background image. Doe anyone know how I can "fix" the height to `420px` for portrait and `320px` for landscape?

Thanks.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd"><head>
<title>Mobile Website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="css/portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)"href="css/landscape.css">

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take out `width=device-width` and just use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

EDIT:
I had this same issue and used the above. However, I didn't have the different css's that you have.

EDIT 2:
Try this and get rid of the 2 different css files and just use one without the all and orientation stuff. Then use the meta view stuff I posted as well. I just tested and this worked for me. It made the background image full length no matter what orientation I used.

```
.ui-page {
    background: url(images/purple.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jostster but it didn't work. I see there that you had the same issue. Don't know why it's not working for me. It's strange because whichever orientation I load it in first it works fine. It's only when I switch orientation that it adds the white space.

Comment: @user1016078 try taking out the css all and stuff and do a cache reset on your device. See if that makes it work. Also what version of jqm are you using?

Comment: Right well I am getting closer. If I set a background colour in those style-sheets then it doesn't happen but if I add in a background image which I want to do then white space gets added when I switch orientation. I am using the guide here to add the background image http://www.roccles.com/?p=201

Comment: @user1016078 Are you setting the background to the page div? If so you will probably need to run the `.page();` again. Or I would edit the jqm css file and edit the theme you are using to use the background image so you can just let jquery worry about all the refresh on orentiation change.

Comment: I am setting the background image to .ui-page . What do you mean by "run the .page(); again"?

Comment: @user1016078 awesome. If this resolved the issue for you be sure to mark it up and check it as accepted answer. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
all and (orientation:portrait)
all and (orientation:landscape)
```

To:

```
all and (max-width: 419px) <--will be used for widths less than 420px
all and (min-width: 420px) <--will be used for widths more than or equal to 420px
```

Here is a tutorial I used a while ago, there are tons out there so if this doesn't answer all your questions just keep Googling: http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/

Comment: You should never hard code pixels. Different devices have different widths.

Comment: Depends on how you want your site designed, you should never never not do anything.

Comment: I know a lot of people say that but they are saying don't hard-code for a specific width/device. It's not a bad idea to split your style-sheets into width-specific sets so your webpage looks good on any width. For instance the `< 420px` style-sheet can use a single column, the `> 420px` style-sheet can use two columns, and you could specify a "desktop" style-sheet that had three columns.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. I will have a read of that tutorial you referenced as I am still having an issue with it.